# Sphinx Search Default Order

Tags: sphinx

I just noticed something about Sphinx Search.  If I choose a particular order, like relevance for example, it seems like if I have a number of items from 1 to 10, for some reason, the relevant returns that come back are still in a numbered order.  i.e. The records will be in the 1-5 range instead of in the 6-10 range.  Is there something I am missing or don't understand?

So, the only way I can get new results to show is to do a sort by ID DESC, but the problem there is I am only getting from the newest ID down and there isn't really any sort on relevance at that point.

Is there some kind of default sort on the back end that can be adjusted?

Comment: So, maybe I am answering my own question, but in my sql query on the back end of things, I just added a ORDER BY ID DESC.  Will this be basically what I need to do?

Comment: Please show your code. There isnt enough information to undestand your issue.